# Using a custom UI with amazon cognito

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I am making a portfolio-building app by hosting reactjs on cloudfront and using serverless lambda as the backend.  I want to have authentication, but I want to really be able to customize the login/sign up page with react.  Is there a way to do this with Cognito, or is there some other technology I should use?  What are my options in this regard?   Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Cognito Hosted UI cannot be customized beyond some custom styles and a custom logo that you're able to configure in the AWS web console.

If you don't need to rely on the Oauth2 features provided by the hosted UI you can have a look at the AWS Amplify project that provides React components for authentication with Cognito. But as I said, if you need the Oauth2 flows in your login pages then the hosted UI is, unfortunately, the only solution as AWS doesn't provide an API for Oauth2.

Comment: Thanks @Tomasz!  Really appreciate it!

Comment: https://www.customizecognito.com/ can be used to help prototype some styling of the form

Comment: That's a very useful tool @Meeses for someone who is happy with the current limitations of Cognito UI customization. The original question was about building a custom UI with frameworks like React.JS

Comment: @Tomasz : what oauth2 features will you loose by using Amplify?

Comment: @Patrick from top of my head: the authorization code flow, and the SSO capability (being able to do passwordless auth to other clients with an endpoint such as /oauth2/authorize)

Answer (score 1):

Based on my experience it's possible to implement a custom UI as part of your application self.

You can implement your custom view in React and then handle all the signIn/signUp/signOut calls using the [Amplify lib](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/emailpassword/q/platform/js)